# At what points on the curve $4(y^2 - 2y - x)(y^2 - 2y + x + 2) = 1$ does $\frac{dy}{dx}$ not exist?

Tags: calculus

I am trying to figure out the answer to this question, but I am a little stumped.

If anyone has any ideas I would be very grateful.

At what points on the curve $4(y^2 - 2y - x)(y^2 - 2y + x + 2) = 1$ does $\frac{dy}{dx}$ not exist?

Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 1):

That would be where the curve is vertical.
Do implicit differentiation, like usual.  Then find $dy/dx$ as a function of $x$ and $y$.  The curve is vertical when BOTH the denominator is zero AND the original equation is true.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing too many calculations, let us review the theory: if we have a curve implicitly defined by an equation $F(x,y)=0$, the chain rule tells us
$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\, \frac{d y}{d x}=0$$
so that
$$\frac{d y}{d x}=-\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}$$
This expression does not exist if the partial derivative $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ is $0$, so this is the first thing we have to check.

Then, derive your equation *only* with respect to $y$:
$$4\,(2 y-2)\,(y^2-2 y+x+2)+4\,(y^2-2 y -x)\,(2 y-2)=0$$
which has the only possible solution $y=1$.

Finally, is there any point with $y=1$ that belongs to the curve? No, because substituting $y=1$ we obtain:
$$-4\,(1+x)^2=1$$
which has no solution.

Of course this is equivalent to obtaining the general expression of $y'$, just it seems computationally easier to work first with $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$, then find points on the curve, rather than the other way round.